# Elastic search error - [prefix] query does not support [prefix]

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When I post the following query, I got an error response

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[prefix] query does not support [prefix]","line":1,"col":119}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[prefix] query does not support [prefix]","line":1,"col":119},"status":400}
```

Here's my POST query:

```
{"from":0,"size":10,"sort":{"_score":"desc"},"query":{"bool":{"must":{"bool":{"should":[[{"prefix":{"title":{"prefix":"of","boost":"1.0"}}}],{"multi_match":{"query":"of","fields":["title^1.0"]}},{"query_string":{"query":"(\"of\")","fields":["title^1.0"]}}]}}}}}
```

How can I make this query work for my autocomplete search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prefix command accepts "value" not "prefix". Also the "boost" value is numeric type, so it shouldn't be enclosed in quotes.

So it should be:

```
{"prefix":{"title":{"value":"of","boost":1.0}}}
```

Instead of:

```
{"prefix":{"title":{"prefix":"of","boost":"1.0"}}}
```